# Creating Dynamic Pivot Item

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

At the moment, I have some JSON string which looks like in this link: http://apibiru.herokuapp.com/v0.1/snack/1/?auth_token=64d362d2e483e8023c46595f83ca8d9555ff6d7cc700a2474fbdbd341c43c1fb

I want to make it so that I make pivot items as much as the array "chunks" in the JSON. This is my attempting code:

```
private void readnow_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string jsonStr = e.Result;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonStr))
            {
                JObject objects = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
                JArray array = (JArray)objects["chunks"];
                Snack.Chunk[] chunks = new Snack.Chunk[array.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
                {
                    PivotItem pivotitem = new PivotItem();
                    chunks[i] = array[i].ToObject<Snack.Chunk>();
                    TextBlock chunk = new TextBlock { Text = chunks[i].content, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap};
                    StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
                    stack.Children.Add(chunk);
                    pivotitem.Content = stack;
                    MainPivot.Items.Add(pivotitem);
                    pivotitem = null;
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check your internet connection");
        }
    }
```

This code is running and I have checked that I have successfully fill 'chunk' completely, but the problem is that no pivot item were made. Where did I go wrong? If you need any details on other class files just tell me. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Don't set the pivotitem to null in the last statement in the for-loop.

Comment: I deleted that line and still doesn't work

Comment: it's all fixed up. Apparently it's because of my fault in other files, Thanks by the way.